# Using django-jenkins with jenkins and docker

Tags: django, unit-testing, docker, jenkins, django-jenkins

I try to present test results in Jenkins on build. My stack is, that I put Django application inside Docker image, and deploy it with Jenkins.

Inside yaml file, where I have run docker container functionality I put running script.

```
- name: Run unit test script
  command: docker exec -i my_container /bin/bash -c './manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage'
```

Build went well, and if I ssh (in terminal) to this machine, and look inside docker container, I can see `reports` folder with reports.

My problem is that inside Jenkins, under Workspace I can see all files but not `reports` folder.

Because of that (I think) if I add `Post-build Action -> Publish JUnit test result report` I can't select folder with reports inside.

**My guess:**

My guess is that Jenkins can't see inside docker image, and somehow copy all files before yaml command is triggered. But I don't know how to solve this.